# What is the best way to pass values from a child ViewController to a parent ViewController in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

Say you have a ViewController that segues into a child ViewController. The child ViewController needs to be prepared with some values, typically set by the parent ViewController in the `prepareForSegue()` function.

Now say that some value in the child ViewController is updated and should be remembered for the next time it is called. What is the best way for the child ViewController to let the parent ViewController know of the updated value, so that it can be considered in subsequent calls to `prepareForSegue()`?

Please elaborate on the persistence/non-persistence of your solution and common/best practices.

Comment: in objective-c or in swift you can pass your data by reference thus modifying your data passed by reference from parent to child in the child will also modify it in the parent, you just have to refresh the view.

Comment: Do you just need to have the value in the child ViewController available to the parent ViewController or do you also must notify the parent ViewController every time that the value changes?

Comment: @xpereta just make it available for next time the child VC is instantiated. No need to keep values in sync for every update.

Comment: Can't you just store the value in a property in the parent ViewController? And update it from the child ViewController when necessary.

Comment: @xpereta, well, that is precisely the point. How does the child VC access any sort of memory of the parent VC? It should not have direct access as it is a child VC.

Answer (score 1):

You can create delegate from your child ViewController. Every time your values (you want to save) update, send it to parent ViewController.

See some example about delegate in here:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/115300/swift-2-tutorial-part-3-tuples-protocols-delegates-and-table-views

Comment: the tutorial you point to does not really cover delegates (only data source, arguably a kind of delegate) and it does not involve nested VC's.